# keyword to search tutorial on android video streaming (To/From a server)

Tags: android, video-streaming

i need to make an application that can retrieve and send video using video streaming. but i just do not have any clue how to make it.

what i understand, video streaming is something like when the user want to watch video from the server like youtube, etc. i also want to add on that the application can send the video to the server using android application.

i am using android 2.2. if anyone is willing to give me any keyword i should search for to get to such a tutorial or any tips i should know, that would be a great help.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As i tried few months before, android versions bellow 4.0 doesn't support live video streaming from phone to the server :(

you can pipeline capturing and sending chunk of video using Threads, so that it feels like a video streaming having very less delay :)

and for stored media content search for RTSP and related protocols for streaming i hope 2.2 supports this .